# Do we need to mark lambda as mutable when capture scope are data members of the class

Tags: c++, lambda

With Lambdas, we use mutable keyword when we need to modify the capturescope element marked under [].

But with class, I am able to modify the data memebers even without marking it as mutable.
Can someone help me with the understanding

````
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Person {

private:
  std::string name{"None"};
  int age{0};
public:
  Person() = default;
  Person(std::string name, int age) : name{name}, age{age} {}
  Person(const Person &p) = default;
  ~Person() = default;
   std::string get_name() const { return name; }
  void set_name(std::string name) {this->name = name; };
  int get_age() const {return age; }
  void set_age(int age) {this->age = age; }
  
  auto change_person1(){return [this] (std::string new_name, int new_age) {name = new_name; age = new_age;};}
  auto change_person2() {return [=] (std::string new_name, int new_age) {name = new_name; age = new_age;};}
  auto change_person3() {return [&] (std::string new_name, int new_age) {name = new_name; age = new_age;};}
};

int main()
{
   Person person;
   auto p1 = person.change_person2();
   p1("Hello", 12);

   std::cout << "Age is "<< person.get_age()<<"\n";
   std::cout << person.get_name();

   return 0;
}```
````

Comment: What you captured is `this`, and `this` is a non-`cost` pointer to the object.

Comment: auto change_person2() {return [=] (std::string new_name, int new_age) {name = new_name; age = new_age;};} In this particular case, we are capturing and modifying the variables. [Name and Age] and that too without the mutable. Any thoughts on this

Answer (score 0):

The members of the class are not captured. The class itself is not captured. What is captured is the `this` *pointer to* the current instance of the class, and you do not modify `this` (in fact, you can't) so there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing `this` in order to modify the class members. `this` isn't a const pointer so you are allowed to modify the members or call non-const methods. If your lambda was inside a const method the usual restrictions would apply whether the lambda is `mutable` or not.

`mutable` is only required when you modify the captured variables themselves.

Comment: auto change_person2() {return [=] (std::string new_name, int new_age) {name = new_name; age = new_age;};}

In this particular case, we are capturing and modifying the variables. [Name and Age] and that too without the mutable. Any thoughts on this

Comment: no, you aren't capturing the variables, you are capturing `this` which then allows you to access the member variables

Comment: if you capture `name` and `age` by value you can't modify them: https://godbolt.org/z/Gc18Ka9aW unless the lambda is `mutable`: https://godbolt.org/z/joEYKab6T

Comment: Alan, please refer the modified snippet, and in this case, even without the mutable keyword usage, i am able to modify the name and age when captured by value.

Answer (score 0):

[=], [&], and [this] are equivalent when capturing an object's member variables - all are captured by reference.
In case of values being captured by reference, we need not to use the mutable keyword.

```
void answer()
{
    std::cout << "\n---Test3 --------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    int x {100};
    
    auto l = [&x] () {
        x += 100;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    };
    
    l();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a Lambda as short hand for writing a functor.

```
int main()
{
     int k = 4;
     auto l = [k](int x){return k + x;}

     std::cout << l(2) << " " << l(2) << "\n";
}
```

This is the equivalent (very similar (or thought of as short hand way)) of writing:

```
class Lambda1
{
    int k;
    public:
        Lambda1(int k): k(k) {}
        int operator()(int x) const {return k+x;}
};
int main()
{
     int k = 4;
     Lambda1 l(k);

     std::cout << l(2) << " " << l(2) << "\n";
}
```

You will notice that the `operator()` is marked `const`.

When you mark a lambda as `mutable` it is the equivalent of removing that const.

```
int main()
{
     int k = 4;
     auto l = [k](int x) mutable {k+=x;return k + x;}

     std::cout << l(2) << " " << l(2) << "\n";
}
```

Now

```
class Lambda1
{
    int k;
    public:
        Lambda1(int k): k(k) {}
        int operator()(int x) {k+=x;return k+x;}
};
int main()
{
     int k = 4;
     Lambda1 l(k);

     std::cout << l(2) << " " << l(2) << "\n";
}
```

---

So if we look at your cases. Here you are using basically doing different ways of capturing `this` (or its reference) `self`.

So you are not allowed to change the pointer `this` or `self`. But as long as these are not const pointer/references you can still change the values of anything that they pointer/refer  at.

```
class Lambda2;
class Person
{
    friend class Lambda2;
    ...
};
class Lambda2
{
    Person& k;
    public:
        Lambda2(Person& k): k(k) {}
        int operator()(std::string name, int age) cosnt  {person.name = name, person.age = age;}
};
int main()
{
     Persn p;
     Lambda2 l(p);

     std::cout << p.get_name() << " " << p.get_age() << "\n";
}
```